# How can we find all the employees has ever taken a fiscal-year long vacation or just more from a schedule table?

Tags: sqlite, nested

How can we find all the employees has ever taken a fiscal year long vacation with one query? This particular company consider its fiscal year duration roughly  consists of the fall quarter of current year , the winter quarter and the spring quarter of the incoming/ (its) next year.
(please also explain a bit not just with a working solution since it would be nice to know the How).

let's say we have a table contains all employees as eid(string).

Then a table a schedule table as eid (string), departid (string), quarter (string), year (integer).
We are given a schedule table to find out all the employees take fiscal-year long vacation or just more. (This question is different than the previous one that I asked, we have a not so nice schedule table instead of a vacation table ) (please also explain a bit not just with a working solution since it would be nice to know the How).

```
employees
+-----+
| id  | 
+-----+ 
| e01 | 
+-----+ 
| e02 |  
+-----+ 
| e03 | 
+-----+ 
| e04 | 
+-----+ 


schedule
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| eid| departid    | quarter     |   year      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Winter      |   2013      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Fall        |   2013      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Spring      |   2013      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Spring      |   2015      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Spring      |   2015      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Spring      |   2015      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e01| marketing01 | Spring      |   2015      |

+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e02| theboard00  | Spring      |   2017      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e02| theboard00  | Winter      |   2019      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e02| theboard00  | Winter      |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e02| enginering01| Winter      |   2020      |

+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e03| marketing01 | Winter      |   2018      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e03| marketing01 | Fall        |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e03| marketing01 | Winter      |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+

| e04| marketing01 | Spring      |   2019      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e04| marketing01 | Spring      |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e04| marketing01 | Spring      |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e04| marketing01 | Spring      |   2018      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+

| e05| marketing01 | Fall        |   2020      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e05| marketing01 | Fall        |   2001      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+

| e06| marketing01 | Fall        |   2016      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e06| marketing01 | Fall        |   2018      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+

| e07| theboard00  | Spring      |   2016      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| e07| theboard00  | Fall        |   2017      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The query should return e02, e03, e05, e06, e07,
since

```
e02 work Spring 2017, Winter 2020 (more than year-long vacation)
e03 work Winter 2018, Winter 2020 (more than year-long vacation)
e05 work Fall   2001, Fall   2020 (way more than year-long vacation)
e06 work Fall   2016, Fall   2018 (way more than year-long vacation)
e07 work Spring 2016, Fall   2017 (year-long vacation)
```

What I have so far from my previous question.

Comment: Employee e01 worked in Fall 2013 and after that in  Fall 2015 but does not exist in the expected results. Why?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Messed up with the data. It should be corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eid, year + (quarter = 'Fall') year
FROM schedule
```

returns distinct rows of each `eid` and every year, but if the `quarter` is `'Fall'` it returns the next year, so that it can be grouped with `'Winter'` and `'Spring'` of the next year.

Then you can use `LAG()` window function to get for each `eid` every year's previous year:

```
SELECT *, LAG(year) OVER (PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year) prev_year
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT eid, year + (quarter = 'Fall') year
  FROM schedule
)
```

and finally filter all the `eid`s for which the difference of year and previous year is greater than 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eid
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(year) OVER (PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year) prev_year
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT eid, year + (quarter = 'Fall') year
    FROM schedule
  )
)
WHERE year - prev_year > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c3b176a7067fb921ee3cf53f5f61235b).
Results:

| eid |
| --- |
| e02 |
| e03 |
| e05 |
| e06 |
| e07 |

Comment: Thank you. but tested it locally with sqlite, why e01 still show up in the result.

Comment: @Johnlee I use your sample data after you edited. Check the demo.

Comment: Yes, you are right again. I have see where the problem is. Thank you. With your example.  got it now.